# Эффект параллакса на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно сделать такой параллакс эффект как здесь http://ljudi_kryma.tass.ru/?

```css
.cover {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 700px;
  background: chocolate;
}

.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">обложка</div>
<div class="container">текст</div>
```

Comment: Это называется параллакс эффект.

Comment: Вот именно это параллаксом не называется

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Не знаю где тут коллеги увидели параллакс, но вот набросок решения.

Краткая суть: есть обложка с фиксированной позицией, она лежит поверх всего.

Есть контейнер с нашим контентом, изначально находится на той же позиции. Его мы по событию скролл возим на величину скролла до упора в в границы страницы.

Есть затемнитель лежащий поверх котнейнера и имеющий те же размеры, обычный черный слой, в зависимости от позиции накручиваем его прозрачность, возим его по полотну параллельно с контейнером.

Есть элемент хинт, имеет размеры контейнера, стоит на фиксированной позиции после обложки. Лежит подо всем, нужен для эмуляции большего размера страницы чтобы не прыгал размер скроллбара.

Основной завтык тут в том как заставить котейнер скроллиться вверх когда нужно вместо того чтобы везти его вверх. Тут помогла проверка scrollTop, если проскроллили страницу больше чем на размер экрана, то элементы не возим.

```js
var win_height = $(window).height();
var height = $('#container').height();
$('#hint, #hider').height(height);

var start_pos = height < win_height ? win_height - height : 0;
var saved_pos = $(document).scrollTop();
var container = $('#container');
var container_top;
var scroll_amount;
container.css({
  'top': start_pos + 'px'
});
$('#hider').css({
  'top': start_pos + 'px'
});
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  current_pos = $(document).scrollTop();
  scroll_amount = current_pos - saved_pos;
  container_top = container.position().top;
  saved_pos = current_pos;
  if ((current_pos <= win_height + scroll_amount) || (container_top < win_height)) {
    var new_top = container_top + scroll_amount;
    if (new_top > win_height) new_top = win_height;
    else if (new_top < start_pos) new_top = start_pos;
    container.css({
      'top': new_top + 'px'
    });
    $('#hider').css({
      'top': new_top + 'px',
      'opacity': (height >= win_height) ? ((win_height - saved_pos) / win_height) :
        ((win_height - container_top) / height)
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#cover {
  top: 0px;
  background: chocolate;
  z-index: 4;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
}

#hider {
  opacity: 1.0;
  background: black;
  z-index: 3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#hint {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100vh;
}

.sized {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sized" id="cover">обложка</div>
<div class="sized" id="container"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</span></div>
<div class="sized" id="hider"></div>
<div class="sized" id="hint"></div>
```

Comment: скролл убрал, по второй претензии не совсем понял. или у меня не воспроизводится или попробуйте перефразировать. или гифку сделайте.

Comment: Понял теперь, расчет был на то, что все блоки имеют размер экрана как на указанной странице. Окей, посмотрю как можно выкрутиться для такой ситуации.

Comment: только ещё когда произошёл скролл надо url сменить

Comment: Я только хотел спросить как вы сделали что бы затемнитель не блокировал контент на фоне как на примере, а оказалось у вас его нет. Есть идеи как реализовать его как на сайте?

Comment: @Telion спасибо за замечание, легко. `pointer-events: none` в css для затемнителя

Comment: @LADYX похоже мы нашли баг местных сниппетов, на jsbin всё ок

Comment: @LADYX понял в чем прикол, здесь при разворачивании на весь экран не происходит перезапуск кода

Comment: @LADYX да вообще можно вынести все предварительные расчеты  в отдельную функцию и запускать при загрузке страницы и по `$( window ).resize()`, но не уверен что все совсем корректно отобразится, возможно придется добавить дополнительный пересчет координат

Answer (score 4):

Самое простое решение, имхо: для `container` устанавливаем `margin-top` >50vh, и при скролле страницы, смещаем фиксированный `cover` вверх на удвоенную величину `window.pageYOffset` (через стиль `top`).
Таким образом, обложка будет "уползать" выше вьюпорта вдвое быстрее, чем выполняется прокрутка. И при полном скрытии обложки, отступ `content`'а сверху будет равен его `margin-top` минус 50vh.
*Есть очевидный нюанс - контент будет двигаться при скролле пока обложка видна. При просмотре на мобильном, это создает некоторое подобие эффекта параллакса (в примере по ссылке из вопроса, такого нет).*
[Демо описанного выше варианта](http://jsbin.com/silesu/edit?output).

**upd:** Только сейчас посмотрел на компе - в отличие от мобильного браузера, все это страшненько смотрится, из-за большей скорости скролла и отсутствия его плавности. Единственным вариантом остается смещение самого `container` через `top`, но это не годится для мобильных браузеров (получается, один способ хорошо выглядит на мобильном браузере, другой - в десктопном, а универсального варианта нет...).
[Демо со сдвигом через `content.style.top` (не для мобильных браузеров, текст будет дергаться)](http://jsbin.com/zuyufuf/edit?js,output).

p.s.: Мой вариант принципиально не отличается от того что указан в предыдущего ответе - в первую очередь, я хотел пояснить саму логику такой реализации.

Comment: @LADYX, я вижу только один вариант как сделать текст неподвижным - это [установка `container.styles.top` в обработчике события `scroll`](http://jsbin.com/zuyufuf/edit?js,output). Но, к сожалению, в мобильном Хроме это работает плохо: текст дергается при прокрутке.

Comment: *И это никак побороть нельзя?* - думаю что нельзя, т.к. браузер фактически два раза меняет позицию элемента (сначала при скролле, затем в JS-обработчике).      Да, `CONTENT_MARGINTOP` - это верхний отступ контента: просто постоянная прибавка к значению `top`. Так я попытался компенсировать резкий скроллинг в Хроме.

Comment: Не понял, во втором демо у вас не дергается текст?

Comment: @yolosora, в хроме на ПК у меня текст не дергается (даже если скроллить быстро), а в мобильном - дергается ужасно при любой скорости скроллинга.

Comment: @yar85 может от разрешения зависит... у вас какое?

Comment: от разрешения не зависит, при плавном скроле все идеально. а при скроллах поворотом колесика или стрелками текст "вибрирует". честно говоря даже не понимаю почему такое происходит, вроде бы даже деления координат никакого нет.